# NGINX force non-ssl for a default connection

Tags: nginx

`http://` works well, however, if I am trying to access `https://` host, I get an error saying "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." (Firefox 8). Furthermore, simply adding `listen 443 ssl default;` messes up the other SSL vir

```
server
{
    listen 443 ssl default;

    server_name _;

    server_name_in_redirect off;

    #rewrite    ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    rewrite ^ http://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server
{
    listen 80 default;

    server_name _;

    server_name_in_redirect off;

    root "/var/www/virtualhosts/dev.anuary.com/default";

    include /etc/nginx/anuary_location_php;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need, at the very least, `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` for the server to be able to complete connections on that port.

This is why you're seeing the connection be reset by nginx - it's got no key to do its SSL negotiation with.

Comment: Hm. So there is no way to force non-ssl connection for people who are trying to use my server from unknown hosts?

Comment: @Guy You certainly can, but you still need a certificate for listening on that port.  Connecting clients are likely to get a warning about a hostname mismatch, but such is life.